# React Native Expo convert URL image to Base64

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am working on a app which loads images from api. The requirement of the app is to store these images offline in app database which is based of sqllite. Only way i think is that to convert images into base64 string & it will be easy for me to show images.

I used RN-Fetch-Blob Library before but expo don't supports that. So i am looking for a way to do that but i didn't find anything.

I tried this library react-native-image-base64

But it donn't work

```
ImgToBase64.getBase64String('http://i.imgur.com/XP2BE7q.jpg')
        .then(base64String => console.log(base64String))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Anyone tell me the how i can convert image to base64 in Expo?

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question, you might want to consider storing the image as BLOB type in your sqlite DB. you may check some examples here: https://medium.com/@ericmorgan1/upload-images-to-firebase-in-expo-c4a7d4c46d06

The idea is, using Expo, we can use the ImagePicker to get the URI, then use the `fetch()` API to retrieve the BLOB data.

Once we get the BLOB data, then we can store that into our SQLite DB.

---

Example:

```
const imageUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/XP2BE7q.jpg';
const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
// This will be the blob data that you will have to store inside your SQLite DB
const blob = await response.blob();
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit, Firebase example is too out of the topic

Comment: firebase or not, it doesn't matter if you checked the link, let me update my answer.